# Calculating seconds to millisecond NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Trying to work out where I have screwed up with trying to create a count down timer which displays seconds and milliseconds. The idea is the timer displays the count down time to an NSString which updates a UILable.

The code I currently have is

```
-(void)timerRun {
    if (self.timerPageView.startCountdown) {
        NSLog(@"%i",self.timerPageView.xtime);

    self.timerPageView.sec = self.timerPageView.sec - 1;

    seconds = (self.timerPageView.sec % 60) % 60 ;
    milliseconds = (self.timerPageView.sec % 60) % 1000;


    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", seconds, milliseconds];
    self.timerPageView.timerText.text = timerOutput;

    if (self.timerPageView.resetTimer == YES) {
       [self setTimer];
}
}
    else {

    }


}

-(void)setTimer{
    if (self.timerPageView.xtime == 0) {
        self.timerPageView.xtime = 60000;
    }
    self.timerPageView.sec = self.timerPageView.xtime;
    self.timerPageView.countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
    self.timerPageView.resetTimer = NO;
}

    int seconds;
    int milliseconds;
    int minutes;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your program crashing?

Comment: Would you care telling us what is not working?

Comment: Are you gonna answer the three questions above?

Comment: The programs running but the times all wrong. Can't match the seconds to their accurate measures such as 60000 millisecs equals 1 min. Millisecs are to fast going through. Basically trying to see if there is something really obviously wrong with the programming maths of the methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a timer that will execute roughly 100 times per second (interval of 0.01).

You decrement a value by `1` each time. Therefore, your `self.timerPageView.sec` variable appears to be hundredths of a second.

To get the number of seconds, you need to divide this value by 100. To get the number of milliseconds, you need to multiply by 10 then modulo by 1000.

```
seconds = self.timerPageView.sec / 100;
milliseconds = (self.timerPageView.sec * 10) % 1000;
```

Update:

Also note that your timer is highly inaccurate. The timer will not repeat EXACTLY every hundredth of a second. It may only run 80 times per second or some other inexact rate.

A better approach would be to get the current time at the start. Then inside your `timerRun` method you get the current time again. Subtract the two numbers. This will give the actual elapsed time. Use this instead of decrementing a value each loop.

Comment: int seconds;
    int milliseconds;
    int minutes;
}

Comment: Yes, I know. But do you see what I'm saying in my answer? Your counter is in hundredths of a second, not milliseconds or seconds or minutes. Your initial value of 60000 is 600 seconds or 10 minutes. Is this what you want?

Comment: looking to start timer from max of 60 secs

Comment: Then make the changes I stated and start your value at 6000, not 60000.

Comment: Also note that you timer is highly inaccurate. The timer will not repeat EXACTLY every hundredth of a second. It may only run 80 times per second or some other inexact rate.

Comment: You my friend get a cookie :D

Comment: Any other way to create a more accurate timer?

Answer (score 3):

These calculations look pretty suspect:

```
seconds = (self.timerPageView.sec % 60) % 60 ;
milliseconds = (self.timerPageView.sec % 60) % 1000;
```

You are using int type calculations (pretty sketchy in their implementation) on a float value for seconds.

```
   NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)(self.timerPageView.sec * 100); //convert to an int
   NSUInteger milliseconds = (NSUInteger) ((self.timerPageView.sec - seconds)* 1000.);
```

Comment: Except the `sec` variable is counting hundredths of a second, not seconds.

Comment: fixed (hopefully) based on Maddy's comment. I better not cross maddy, because he gets, ummm...   maddy.

Comment: I don't know what that is supposed to mean. Sorry if you don't like me being helpful.

Comment: This accurate, in time wise?

Comment: Sorry rmaddy, I was trying to be funny (I'm on pain meds at the moment, and maybe not so funny) I really like your help you are like the bomb-diggety on ios on here.

Answer (score 3):

You set a time interval of 0.01, which is every 10 milliseconds, 0.001 is every millisecond.
Even so, NSTimer is not that accurate, you probably won't get it to work every 1 ms.  It is fired from the run loop so there is latency and jitter.

Comment: Any solution to that issue?